# Ninject fails to resolve interface type when the concrete type derives from an abstract base class

Tags: compact-framework, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, abstract-class, ninject

I have a problem with Ninject trying to resolve an interface type where the concrete type derives from an abstract base class that implements the interface.

**EDIT: This is on Windows Mobile using .NET CF.**

My particular issue involves presenters and views, so I stick to that in this example instead of foos and bars.

I want to inject factories for presenters and views to allow for late creation of those instances deep down the UI view stack.

Below I've omitted all error checking for better readability.

My factory interface:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}
```

My presenter and view:

```
public sealed class Presenter
{
    private readonly View view;

    public Presenter(View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

public sealed class View
{
    public View()
    {
    }
}
```

First, I'll show what works perfectly, that Ninject resolves as expected. This will not include the abstract base class I mentioned at the beginning. After this, I'll add the slight modifications with the abstract base class that will make Ninject throw when trying to resolve the dependencies.

We see above that the presenter depends on the view, so the presenter factory will depend on the view factory:

```
public sealed class GoodPresenterFactory : IFactory<Presenter>
{
    private readonly IFactory<View> viewFactory;

    public GoodPresenterFactory(IFactory<View> viewFactory)
    {
        this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
    }

    public Presenter Create()
    {
        return new Presenter(this.viewFactory.Create());
    }
}

public sealed class ViewFactory : IFactory<View>
{
    public ViewFactory()
    {
    }

    public View Create()
    {
        return new View();
    }
}
```

Wiring this up with Ninject:

```
Bind<IFactory<Presenter>>().To<GoodPresenterFactory>();
Bind<IFactory<View>>().To<ViewFactory>();
```

And then resolving the presenter factory:

```
var presenterFactory = container.Get<IFactory<Presenter>>();
```

Everything up until now works perfectly. The dependency on the view factory inside the presenter factory is resolved as expected.

Now, I have a million classes that looks like GoodPresenterFactory above and I therefore wanted a small base class to handle some trivial common stuff, like the dependency on the view factory in the presenter factory:

```
public abstract class FactoryBase<T, U> : IFactory<T>
{
    protected readonly U dependency;

    protected FactoryBase(U dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public abstract T Create();
}
```

Then the presenter factory will change and something in that change will make Ninject fail resolving:

```
public sealed class BadPresenterFactory : FactoryBase<Presenter, IFactory<View>>
{
    public BadPresenterFactory(IFactory<View> viewFactory)
        : base(viewFactory)
    {
    }

    public override Presenter Create()
    {
        return new Presenter(this.dependency.Create());
    }
}
```

And changing the Ninject wiring accordingly:

```
Bind<IFactory<Presenter>>().To<BadPresenterFactory>();
Bind<IFactory<View>>().To<ViewFactory>();
```

Those changes will make Ninject throw an ArgumentNullException when doing

```
var presenterFactory = container.Get<IFactory<Presenter>>();
```

Call stack from the exception:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParentDefinition()
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(MemberInfo member, Type caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.IsDefined(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Attribute.IsDefined(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Attribute.IsDefined(MemberInfo element, Type attributeType)
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.HasAttribute(MemberInfo member, Type type)
at Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject(MemberInfo member)
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<>c__DisplayClassa.<SelectMethodsForInjection>b__9(IInjectionHeuristic h)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<SelectMethodsForInjection>b__8(MethodInfo m)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<WhereIterator>d__0`1.MoveNext()
at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.MethodReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan)
at Ninject.Planning.Planner.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetPlan>b__0(IPlanningStrategy s)
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type)
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__4(IContext context)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__d`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b0`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
at NinjectTest.Program.Main()
```

If I modify `FactoryBase` so that it has no dependency, it's just a naked base class, then Ninject also fails.

```
public abstract class NakedFactoryBase<T> : IFactory<T>
{
    protected NakedFactoryBase()
    {
    }

    public abstract T Create();
}

public sealed class PointlessPresenterFactory : NakedFactoryBase<Presenter>
{
    private readonly IFactory<View> viewFactory;

    public PointlessPresenterFactory(IFactory<View> viewFactory)
    {
        this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
    }

    public override Presenter Create()
    {
        return new Presenter(this.viewFactory.Create());
    }
}
```

As you can see, that failing `PointlessPresenterFactory` is identical to the succeeding `GoodPresenterFactory`, apart from the direct `IFactory<Presenter>` implementation in `GoodPresenterFactory`, as opposed to the completeley naked base class used in `PointlessPresenterFactory`.

Any idea why Ninject fails to resolve when the factory base class is used?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening but it's a very good question, well written with good documentation. I'm eager to see the answer. Since @Nate Kohari is on Stack Overflow, I would think you'll get an answer.

Comment: I copied all of your code exactly and I was not able to get the error. What version of ninject are you using? (I'm using 2.2.0.1)

Comment: @John Bledsloe: @Nate Kohari isnt exactly killing himself on SO though is he :P @Remo Gloor will be along no doubt!

Comment: @Ruben: Exactly. @Johann. Same here, I can't reproduce the issue. And from the stacktrace I'm pretty sure that you aren't using the latest version as we do not use Attribute.IsDefined anymore because there is a bug in attribute reflection as you have just proved with your code.

Comment: @Remo @ryber: I'm using Ninject-2.2.1.0-release-netcf-3.5.zip from https://github.com/ninject/ninject/downloads - looks like the latest one. When you tried to reproduce it, did you use .NET CF? (the question is tagged "compact-framework" but I didn't mention that in the question text)

Comment: Seems that I have missed that you are using CF. And it seems you have found another bug in Attribute.IsDefined(). I have no CF test environment at hand atm. Can you test what happens when you execute typeof(BadPresenterFactory).GetMethod("Create").IsDefined(typeof(InjectAttribute), true). I expect it to throw a NullReferenceException. An if so we have to find a workaround for this CF bug.

Comment: @Remo: Good analysis. ArgumentNullException was thrown. Stacktrace:
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParentDefinition()
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(MemberInfo member, Type caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.IsDefined(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)

Comment: @Remo: Any ideas for a workaround inside of Ninject? I'd rather not ditch the in-between-base-class... ;-)

Comment: There are several options. 
1. We have to find a workaround for CF for getting attributes from abstract (generic?) methods
2. We do not support that CF can inherit the InjectAttribute
3. Catch the exception and return false, wich means that the InheritAttribute can not be inherited in some undefined cases where the CF throws an unexpected exception

Comment: I added a task to our backlog for the next release

Comment: @Remo: That's plain brilliant! I'll be sure to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in build 2.3.0.46 and will be part of the next release (2.4).

NOTE: because CF seems not to allow to detect is a method is generic or not the Inject attribute can not be defined on base methods anymore. It has to be defined on the overload method.